# Swift: How to determine when an email is sent in order to update table view?

Tags: ios, swift, email, swift3, mfmailcomposer

I'm creating an application that allows the user to send a simple email via MFMailComposer. I've already configured that part but i'm trying to figure out, once the email is sent, how do i update the table view showing something like "Email sent" with possibly a time stamp?
so far i have a string array that should store the data for emails sent:

```
var emailSent = [String]()
```

Any suggestion or help would truly be appreciated!

Comment: What part exactly do you need help with? Do you have code in the mail composer delegate method to check the result?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property in your tableview controller called selectedCellIndexPathRow which you would set in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedCellIndexPathRow = indexPath.row
    //Open your MailComposeViewController
}
```

Then, you could do the following once the email is sent:

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    if result.rawValue == MFMailComposeResult.Sent.rawValue {
        emailSent[selectedCellIndexPathRow] = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom subclass of `MFMailComposerViewController`, override `setMessageBody` and store the sent body for late usage:

```
class MyMailComposer: MFMailComposeViewController {
    var lastSentBody:String?

    override func setMessageBody(_ body: String, isHTML: Bool) {
        lastSentBody = body
        super.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: isHTML)
    }
}
```